# Removing calls to glGenVertexArrays() results in black screen

Tags: vba, opengl, glsl, vbo

So, I previously used vertex array buffers (Core Profile 3.3), setup as follows:

```
int offset = 0;

glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_vba);
glBindVertexArray(m_vba);
glGenBuffers(1, &m_vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vbo);

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, TOTAL_DATA_SIZE, nullptr, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// Vertex data
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, offset, VERTEX_DATA_SIZE, vertices);
offset += VERTEX_DATA_SIZE;

// Normal data
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, offset, NORMAL_DATA_SIZE, normals);
offset += NORMAL_DATA_SIZE;

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, reinterpret_cast<GLvoid *>(VERTEX_DATA_SIZE));
```

I'm not using an index buffer. Rendering like this:

```
glBindVertexArray(m_vba);    
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, NUM_VERTICES);
```

This has worked perfectly fine. However, I found out that glGenVertexArrays() might not be available e.g. on Android. Therefore I started to remove it. And there's the problem that's driving me crazy.

If I remove the vba stuff from the data init like this:

```
int offset = 0;

glGenBuffers(1, &m_vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vbo);

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, TOTAL_DATA_SIZE, nullptr, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// Vertex data
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, offset, VERTEX_DATA_SIZE, vertices);
offset += VERTEX_DATA_SIZE;

// Normal data
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, offset, NORMAL_DATA_SIZE, normals);
offset += NORMAL_DATA_SIZE;

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, reinterpret_cast<GLvoid *>(VERTEX_DATA_SIZE));
```

..and render like this:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vbo);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, reinterpret_cast<GLvoid *>(VERTEX_DATA_SIZE));

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, NUM_VERTICES);
```

..I get just a black screen. And the thing that I don't understand is, that if I add somewhere in the code e.g. AFTER the data setup:

```
GLuint foo;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &foo);
glBindVertexArray(foo);
```

Then everything is rendered again correctly. Are there some side-effects that causes this? I don't bind this "foo" buffer ever again after setup and it still works despite multiple objects being rendered sequentally with their own similar buffers!

Apparently things don't go as I predict :) Question is, what should I change in my code after removing glGenVertexArrays()? What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Using a user-generated VAO is just madatory in a GL 3.x core profile. From the 3.3 core spec, E2.2 removed features:

> Client vertex and index arrays - all vertex array attribute and
>   element array index pointers must refer to buffer objects. **The
>   default vertex array object (the name zero) is also deprecated.**
>   Calling VertexAttribPointer when no buffer object **or no vertex array
>   object is bound** will generate an INVALID_OPERATION error, as will
>   calling any array drawing command when no vertex array object is
>   bound.

Comment: Thanks! You just saved my weekend :)